# How do I make my second dropdown dependent on the first in Springboot Thymeleaf?

Tags: spring, thymeleaf, dropdown

I have Studyfields and Modules and I only want the Modules for the respective Studyfield to be displayed in the dropdown. Like you can see at the moment it shows all Modules in the second Dropdown. How can I only show the Module to the respective StudyField in the second Dropdown?

This is my code:

View:

```
            <select  style="margin: 10px" name="studyfields" id="studyfields" th:required="required">
                <option th:each="studyField : ${studyFields}" th:value="${studyField.getId()}" th:text="${studyField.getStudyField()}" >Select a Studyfield</option>
            </select>
            <div id="test1" style="display: none">
            <label for="modules">Modul:</label>
            <select  style="margin: 10px" name="modules" id="modules" th:required="required">
                <option th:each="module : ${modules}" th:value="${module.getId()}" th:text="${module.getName()}" >Select a Studyfield</option>
            </select>
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class QuestionController {

    private final QuestionService questionService;
    private final CommentService commentService;
    private final StudyFieldService studyFieldService;
    private final ModuleService moduleService;
    private final UserService userService;

    public QuestionController(QuestionService questionService, CommentService commentService,
                              StudyFieldService studyFieldService,
                              ModuleService moduleService, UserService userService) {
        this.questionService = questionService;
        this.commentService = commentService;
        this.studyFieldService = studyFieldService;
        this.moduleService = moduleService;
        this.userService = userService;

    }

    @GetMapping("/question/{id}")
    public String showQuestion(@PathVariable long id, Model model) {
        Question question = questionService.getQuestionById(id).orElseThrow(QuestionNotFound::new);
        List<Comment> comments = commentService.getCommentsByQuestionId(id);
        model.addAttribute("studyFields", studyFieldService.getAllStudyFields());
        model.addAttribute("modules", moduleService.getAllModules());
        model.addAttribute("question", question);
        model.addAttribute("comments", comments);
        return "question";
    }

    @GetMapping("/add-question")
    public String goToAddQuestion(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("question", new Question());
        model.addAttribute("studyFields", studyFieldService.getAllStudyFields());
        model.addAttribute("modules", moduleService.getAllModules());
        return "add-question";
    }
```

Module Service:

```
@Service
public class ModuleService {

    private final ModuleRepository moduleRepository;

    public ModuleService(ModuleRepository moduleRepository) {
        this.moduleRepository = moduleRepository;
    }

    public Optional<Module> getModuleById(long id){
        return moduleRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public List<Module> getAllModules() {
        return moduleRepository.findAll();
    }

    public List<Module> getAllModulesByStudyField(StudyField studyField) {
        return moduleRepository.findAllByStudyField(studyField);
    }

    public List<Module> getAllModulesByStudyFieldId(long id) {
        return getAllModules().stream()
            .filter(module -> module.getStudyField().getId() == id).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }


}
```

StudyField Service:

```
@Service
public class StudyFieldService {
    private final StudyFieldRepository studyFieldRepository;

    public StudyFieldService(StudyFieldRepository studyFieldRepository) {
        this.studyFieldRepository = studyFieldRepository;
    }

    public Optional<StudyField> getStudyFieldById(long id) {
        return studyFieldRepository.findById(id);
    }

    public List<StudyField> getAllStudyFields() {
        return studyFieldRepository.findAll();
    }

    public StudyField addStudyField(StudyField studyField) {
        return studyFieldRepository.save(studyField);
    }

    public StudyField getStudyFieldByName(String studyFieldName){return studyFieldRepository.getStudyFieldByStudyField(studyFieldName);}
}
```

Comment: You will need JS to tackle this. This might help you - https://github.com/ajkr195/SpringBootDataCascadeDropDown

Comment: You can use JS like Ajay states, or it is also possible to use HTMX (https://htmx.org/examples/value-select/)